# Программы с API для работы с 3g модемами

Tags: linux, windows, поиск-программ, модемы, 3g

Есть необходимость отсылать и принимать смс и ussd запросы с помощью модема, возможно есть готовые скрипты/библиотеки/софт под win или nix которые можно легко подключить к своему коду? Подскажите в каком направлении искать

Comment: [программы echo и cat — ваши друзья](http://onedev.net/post/911)

Comment: @alexanderbarakin интерфейсный вариант, но хочется уйти от работы с at командами, возможно есть что то более высокоуровневое?

Comment: да куда ж ещё выше уровнем, чем echo и cat??? мышкой, что ли, кнопочки нажимать?

Comment: @user254893, по ссылке есть питоний скрипт для отправки ussd... допили его до sms и будет высокоуровневая морда....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SMS прекрасно отсылаются через `gnokii`:

`echo "Test SMS" |gnokii --sendsms +79xxxxxxxxx`

Насчёт USSD — думаю, что засылка AT-команд напрямик в модем должна работать.

Comment: то что надо, в ussd есть проблема хождения по костылям кодировок